# Как вывести ошибки нескольких интупов с типом file в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть от 1 до 10 `<input name="photo[]" type="file">"`

```html
 @if ($errors->has("photo"))
      <span class="invalid-feedback">
           <strong class="error">{{ $errors->first("photo.0") }}</strong>
       </span>
 @endif
```

`'photo.*' => 'required_unless:type_of_content,is_information',`
    я и так пытался 
    `'photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',`

Почему мне не приходит ошибка ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы почти были правы, нужно было сделать вот так к примеру:

```
<input name="photo[][file]" type="file">
```

И валидатор:

```
'photo.*.file' => 'required_unless:type_of_content,is_information'
```

Подробнее можете прочитать в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays).

Comment: Как вывести ошибки через $errors ?

Comment: Так же - photo.0.file и т.д.

Comment: Кривоватая структура выйдет с `[][file]`. Лишний уровень вложенности.

Comment: Скажите спасибо разработчикам за такую, раньше были костыли ещё по хуже.